# delete a pattern within a file

Tags: linux, fasta

I have a fasta file containing thousands of sequences.
It appears with this format

```
>3276_2258569   M05025:154:000000000-BVP4M:1:1101:17272:1161 1:N:0:TGGTGG       orig_bc=TGCGA   new_bc=TGCGA    bc_diffs=0
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258570   M05025:154:000000000-BVP4M:1:1101:22227:1193 1:N:0:TGGTGG       orig_bc=TGCGA   new_bc=TGCGA    bc_diffs=0
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258571   M05025:154:000000000-BVP4M:1:1101:13340:1215 1:N:0:TGGTGG       orig_bc=TGCGA   new_bc=TGCGA    bc_diffs=0
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
```

I would like to remove most parts of header as the following

```
>3276_2258569
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258570 
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258571
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
```

I tried to use

```
sed -e "s/M.bc_diffs=0//g" myfile.fasta
```

But I do not obtain the desired results.
How could remove those pattern on my sequence header?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664261/multifasta-header-trimming

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:]]+).*/\1/' in.fa > out.fa
```

Or, even easier using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' in.fa > out.fa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl command

```
$ perl -ne  ' s/(\S+)(.*)/$1/g if /^>/; print ' bing.fasta
>3276_2258569
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258570
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT
>3276_2258571
AAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAATAACCTGGTACTGATGCTGGCCCTTTAAC
TGAGGGCATGTGCTCGTATCATCTTATTTATCTCCTCTTGTGCACCTTTTGTAGTCTTTGAAGCTTTCGCAGTCAAATGC
GGTTTGGGGGCTTGAGCTTGCAAAAGTCCTTCCCCTGCTT

$
```