# Multifasta file header trimming

Tags: bash, awk, sequence, fasta

I have a Multi-fasta file, and I want to delete specific parts of the headers for every fasta header in the file. For example:

```
>Viridibacillus_arenosi_FSL_R5_0213-BK137_RS04360-22-CBS_domain-containing_protein <unknown description>
GCTAATGAAGTTATTGGCCTAGTGACAGAAAGGGATATAAAAAACGCGCTTCCTTCTTCC
CTGCTC------AAA
>Viridibacillus_arvi_DSM16317-AMD00_RS08865-16-acetoin_utilization_protein_AcuB <unknown description>
GCGAATGAAGTTATTGGCCTAGTAACAGAAAGGGATATAAAAAACGCCCTTCCATCTTCC
CTGCTC------AAA
```

I want to delete the parts after "-" in the header that is `-BK137_RS04360-22-CBS_domain-containing_protein <unknown description>` and `-AMD00_RS08865-16-acetoin_utilization_protein_AcuB <unknown description>`.

I tried

```
 cut -d '-' -f 1 your_file.fasta > new_file.fasta
```

and

```
 awk '{split($0,a,"-"); if(a[1]) print ">"a[1]; else print; }' my_file.fasta > new_file.fasta
```

But this is an alignment file, and it removed the **"-"** in my sequence as well, which of course I don't want.

My expected output is:

```
>Viridibacillus_arenosi_FSL_R5_0213
GCTAATGAAGTTATTGGCCTAGTGACAGAAAGGGATATAAAAAACGCGCTTCCTTCTTCC
CTGCTC------AAA
>Viridibacillus_arvi_DSM16317-AMD00_RS08865
GCGAATGAAGTTATTGGCCTAGTAACAGAAAGGGATATAAAAAACGCCCTTCCATCTTCC
CTGCTC------AAA
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Hi, I need to delete part of the header of the multifasta file, after the symbol "-" in the fasta header. I try cut -d '-' -f 1 your_file.fasta > new_file.fasta, but this is an alignment file, it removed the "-" in my sequence as well. Sorry is this a correct forum to ask?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done in the following way:

```
awk -F"-" '/^>/{print $1; next}1' in.fasta > out.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` processes all the lines in the same way, but you need to process only a subset of lines, the ones that start with `>`. You can try with `awk`:

```
awk -F- '{if ($0 ~ /^>/) {print $1} else {print $0}}' in.fasta > out.fasta
```

This uses `-` as separator and in every line, it checks if it starts with `>`. If true, then only print the first field; if false, print everything.

The command can even be shortened a little bit.